# pci express connector mechanical feature

Tags: pcie

What is the overhang on pci express connectors for? Is it for a rarely used board latching feature?
I am referring to the feature being pointed to in this picture.

[image: PCI Express connector with arrow]

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, this feature is for optional fastening of PCIe cards and it's known as *retention ridge*.

Quoting from the *PCI Express® Card Electromechanical Specification (Rev. 2.0)*:

> an optional ridge feature is defined on the top of the connector housing on one side.
> This feature can be used to facilitate card retention.  A retention clip may be mounted
> on an add-in card and latched on the ridge.